# Horizontally center object inside DIV

Tags: javascript

I am trying to center a button inside a div horizontally but am having no luck:

```
var x = document.createElement("div"); // the div container
x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
x.style.width = "200px";
x.style.height = "200px";   
document.body.appendChild(x);

var y = document.createElement("input"); // the button to be centered inside div "x"
y.type = "button";
y.value = "test button";
y.style.marginLeft = "auto";
y.style.marginRight = "auto";
x.appendChild(y);
```

I tried doing `y.style.textAlign = "center"`, `"y.style.margin = "auto 0"`. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/5tffD/1/

Comment: hm? why would I put x.style.textAlign when I'm centering 'y' not 'x'?

Comment: You're setting the alignment of the text-line of the DIV. The DIV is the owner of the text-line.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
x.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5tffD/3/

It is not possible to individually align elements. You can only align a text-line as a whole, by setting the `text-align` property on the element which holds the text-line (in this case, the DIV element).

Notice how this differs from the `vertical-align` property, which *does* enable you to individually align elements.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is this the only way of doing this? Or is there some other more standard way?

Comment: @user1019031 I'd define a CSS class for those CSS properties... **See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/5tffD/4/

Comment: Hm last question, how would you center it vertically?

Comment: verticalAlign = "middle?" doesn't work on x... how do I do it?

Comment: @user1019031 You can make it work by setting the `line-height` property to the same value as the `height` property. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/5tffD/5/

Answer (score 0):

here are several methods for centering:

1) anything inside a div:

```
<div align="center"> text or smth </div>
```

2) For a text (maybe images too):

```
<center> text </center>
```

3) for frames or images

```
<img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" align="center" src="imageee.jpg" />
```

4) just the positioning correctly:

```
<div style="width:80%;margin-left:10%;"> content </div>
```